# Is there an online guide on how to visualise different kinds of survey question types (multiple choice, ranking the options, etc) in Microsoft Excel?

Tags: data-visualization, survey, excel

Is there an online guide on how to visualise different kinds of survey question types (multiple choice, ranking the options, etc) in Microsoft Excel?

In particular, I am interested in how to visualise data where over 100 respondents from a couple of regions of the world are asked to rank numerous possible options. The different options to be ranked are the headers for separate columns in excel and in each corresponding row there is a cell containing a ranking that indicate ranking given by a respondent who is named in the 1st column (and categorised by which region of the world they are in, in the second column).

However, I also have some other survey questions which I have visualised in different round-about ways. I hope there is a more systematic approach that I can adopt.

Comment: What it is that you are looking for, visualization or a book about how to manipulate cells in excel? They are two completely different things. The Excel is only a tool for the visualization.

Answer (score 1):

Some charting resources for Excel:

- [Jon Peltier](http://peltiertech.com/) has online guides and Excel charting add-ins for sale
- [Jorge Camoes](http://www.excelcharts.com/blog/) has a book, blog and Excel dashboard tutorial
- [Stephanie Evergreen](http://stephanieevergreen.com/) has a book, blog and workshops using Excel